# How to provide values to the read command in script when run in nohup mode. Ex. in body

Tags: shell-script

If I have two `read` commands in the script and I have to run in `nohup` mode, then how can I give values using echo command.

Eg. script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "/n read the value1" 
read info1 
echo "/n read the value2" 
read info2
 echo "$info1 $info2">>log.txt
```

I have to run this is `nohup` mode then how can I provide the values to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible. You can do something like this:

```
nohup sh -c "printf 'foo\nbar\n' | myScript.sh"
```

That will pass `foo` and `bar` as input.

---

But don't do that. Just don't use `read`. In fact, I can't even think of any good reason to *ever* use `read` inside a script. I'm sure there are some edge cases where it is necessary, but you should avoid it whenever possible. Having your users type in data is cumbersome, prone to errors, and makes automating your script impossible.

So just change your script to read the data from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh 
info1="$1"
info2="$2"
 echo "$info1 $info2">>log.txt
```

Then, run your script with whatever you want as parameters:

```
myScript.sh foo bar
```

or

```
myScript.sh 'this one has spaces!' bar
```

Comment: A lot of learning in just 30s. Great answer. Thanks :)